# How to redirect 'print' output to a file?

Tags: python, io, file-writing

I want to redirect the print to a .txt file using Python. I have a `for` loop, which will `print` the output for each of my .bam file while I want to redirect **all** output to one file. So I tried to put:

```
f = open('output.txt','w')
sys.stdout = f
```

at the beginning of my script. However I get nothing in the .txt file.
My script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os,sys
import subprocess
import glob
from os import path

f = open('output.txt','w')
sys.stdout = f

path= '/home/xxx/nearline/bamfiles'
bamfiles = glob.glob(path + '/*.bam')

for bamfile in bamfiles:
    filename = bamfile.split('/')[-1]
    print 'Filename:', filename
    samtoolsin = subprocess.Popen(["/share/bin/samtools/samtools","view",bamfile],
                                  stdout=subprocess.PIPE,bufsize=1)
    linelist= samtoolsin.stdout.readlines()
    print 'Readlines finished!'
```

So what's the problem? Any other way besides this `sys.stdout`?

I need my result look like:

```
Filename: ERR001268.bam
Readlines finished!
Mean: 233
SD: 10
Interval is: (213, 252)
```

Comment: Why not use `f.write(data)`?

Comment: yeah, but I have several data for each bam file (mean, SD,interval...), how can I put these data one by one?

Comment: @Eran Zimmerman: `f.write(line)` does not add a line break to the data.

Comment: You're right, my bad. Could always `f.write(line+'\n')`, however..

Comment: you don't see anything because you aren't writing enough, in which case you need to call .flush() on the file. And for some editors like kate, even with auto-reload enabled, for some unknown reason, you have to re-open the file too to see the changes.

Answer (score 450, accepted):

The most obvious way to do this would be to print to a file object:

```
with open('out.txt', 'w') as f:
    print('Filename:', filename, file=f)  # Python 3.x
    # print >> f, 'Filename:', filename   # Python 2.x
```

However, redirecting stdout also works for me.  It is probably fine for a one-off script such as this:

```
import sys

orig_stdout = sys.stdout
f = open('out.txt', 'w')
sys.stdout = f

for i in range(2):
    print('i = ', i)

sys.stdout = orig_stdout
f.close()
```

Since Python 3.4 there's a simple context manager available to do this [in the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout):

```
from contextlib import redirect_stdout

with open('out.txt', 'w') as f:
    with redirect_stdout(f):
        print('data')
```

Redirecting externally from the shell itself is another option, and often preferable:

```
./script.py > out.txt
```

Other questions:

What is the first filename in your script?  I don't see it initialized.

My first guess is that glob doesn't find any bamfiles, and therefore the for loop doesn't run.  Check that the folder exists, and print out bamfiles in your script.

Also, use [os.path.join and os.path.basename](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html) to manipulate paths and filenames.

Comment: Line 8 of your code uses a variable named filename, but it hasn't been created yet.  Later in the loop you use it again, but not relevant.

Comment: Bad practice to change sys.stdout if you don't need to.

Comment: @my I'm not convinced it is bad for a simple script like this.

Comment: +1 Haha well you can have my upvote because it's the right way to do it if you absolutely must do it the wrong way... But I still say you should do it with regular file output.

Comment: instead of orig_stdout = sys.stdout then sys.stdout = orig_stdout you can just do sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__

Comment: That's not a good habit to get into; if stdout has already been redirected, the association will be lost.

Comment: `open()` not `file()`

Comment: How to redirect and print the output on the console ? Seems the "print()" in Python cannot be shown when the stdrr is redirected ?

Comment: @exteralvictor  Sounds like you are looking for the `tee file.out` command.  If on Windows, perhaps duplicate the print() call, one with `file=f`, one without.  A simple wrapping function could automate.

Comment: Why it's a bad habit? Actually that's the easiest way to pipe the prints of an actively developed script to a logfile.

Comment: How I append output to targer file with this method "./script.py > out.txt" ? I don't want to owerrite the file.

Comment: @UğurGürkanTosun , `./script.py >> out.txt`  See the double arrow?

Comment: @exteral: you have to flush the file (call .flush()) to get the output to show

Answer (score 104):

You can redirect print with the `file` argument (in Python 2 there was the `>>` operator instead).

```
f = open(filename,'w')
print('whatever', file=f) # Python 3.x
print >>f, 'whatever'     # Python 2.x
```

In most cases, you're better off just writing to the file normally.

```
f.write('whatever')
```

or, if you have several items you want to write with spaces between, like `print`:

```
f.write(' '.join(('whatever', str(var2), 'etc')))
```

Comment: If there are a lot of output statements these can get old fast.  The posters original idea is valid; there is something else wrong with the script.

Comment: Poster's original idea is absolutely invalid. There's no reason to redirect stdout here, since he already gets the data into a variable.

Comment: I think he meant "technically valid", in that you can, in fact, redirect `sys.stdout`, not that it was a good idea.

Answer (score 61):

[Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print) or [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) API reference:

> `print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)`
>
> The *file* argument must be an object with a `write(string)` method; if it is not present or `None`, [`sys.stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdout) will be used. Since printed arguments are converted to text strings, `print()` cannot be used with binary mode file objects. For these, use `file.write(...)` instead.

Since [file object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object) normally contains `write()` method, all you need to do is to pass a [file object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object) into its argument.

#### Write/Overwrite to File

```
with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    print('hello world', file=f)
```

#### Write/Append to File

```
with open('file.txt', 'a') as f:
    print('hello world', file=f)
```

Comment: I just confused why some of those earlier answers were to monkey patch the global `sys.stdout` :(

Comment: Say, you have some legacy codes (2.7) with print statements (instead of logs) all over the file. Now, you want those to be logged into file for debug/investigation purpose. In this case, modifying the global stdout is preferable to modifying each and every print statement. Just my opinion.

Answer (score 46):

#### Don't use `print`, use `logging`

You can change `sys.stdout` to point to a file, but this is a pretty clunky and inflexible way to handle this problem.  Instead of using `print`, use the [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/logging.html) module.

With `logging`, you can print just like you would to `stdout`, or you can also write the output to a file.  You can even use the different message levels (`critical`, `error`, `warning`, `info`, `debug`) to, for example, only print major issues to the console, but still log minor code actions to a file.

#### A simple example

Import `logging`, get the `logger`, and set the processing level:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) # process everything, even if everything isn't printed
```

If you want to print to stdout:

```
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.INFO) # or any other level
logger.addHandler(ch)
```

If you want to also write to a file (if you only want to write to a file skip the last section):

```
fh = logging.FileHandler('myLog.log')
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) # or any level you want
logger.addHandler(fh)
```

Then, wherever you would use `print` use one of the `logger` methods:

```
# print(foo)
logger.debug(foo)

# print('finishing processing')
logger.info('finishing processing')

# print('Something may be wrong')
logger.warning('Something may be wrong')

# print('Something is going really bad')
logger.error('Something is going really bad')
```

To learn more about using more advanced `logging` features, read the excellent [`logging` tutorial in the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/howto/logging.html).

Comment: Hi, I want to use this logging for writing the console data to the log file with the time like at which time that data is taken. But i am not able to understand the logging function or library properly. Can you help me with this

Comment: @haris Read through the [Python docs' logging tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.5/howto/logging.html) and check out examples in other questions on Stack Overflow (there are a lot of them). If you are still unable to get it to work, ask a new question.

Comment: To print multiple variables like 'a' and 'b', for print function you can just do `print(a, b)`. In logging, you have to do `logger.info('%s %s' %(a, b))`, or `logger.info(f'{a}, {b}')`, both are much harder.

Answer (score 42):

This works perfectly:

```
import sys
sys.stdout=open("test.txt","w")
print ("hello")
sys.stdout.close()
```

Now the hello will be written to the test.txt file. Make sure to close the `stdout` with a `close`, without it the content will not be save in the file

Comment: but even if we perform `sys.stdout.close()` , if you type anything in python shell it will show error as `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.` http://imgur.com/a/xby9P. Best way to handle this is follow what @Gringo Suave posted

Answer (score 15):

The easiest solution isn't through python; its through the shell.  From the first line of your file (`#!/usr/bin/python`) I'm guessing you're on a UNIX system.  Just use `print` statements like you normally would, and don't open the file at all in your script.  When you go to run the file, instead of

```
./script.py
```

to run the file, use

```
./script.py > <filename>
```

where you replace `<filename>` with the name of the file you want the output to go in to.  The `>` token tells (most) shells to set stdout to the file described by the following token.

One important thing that needs to be mentioned here is that "script.py" needs to be made executable for `./script.py` to run.

So before running `./script.py`,execute this command

`chmod a+x script.py`
(make the script executable for all users)

Comment: ./script.py > <filename> 2>&1

You need to capture stderr as well.  2>&1 will do that

Comment: @rtaft Why?  The question specifically wants to pipe the output of `print` to a file.  It would be reasonable to expect stdout (stack traces and the like) to still print to the terminal.

Comment: He said it wasn't working, mine wasn't working either.  I later discovered that this app I'm working on was configured to direct everything to stderr...idk why.

Answer (score 13):

If you are using Linux I suggest you to use the `tee` command. The implementation goes like this:

```sh
python python_file.py | tee any_file_name.txt
```

If you don't want to change anything in the code, I think this might be the best possible solution. You can also implement logger but you need do some changes in the code.

Answer (score 4):

You may not like this answer, but I think it's the RIGHT one. Don't change your stdout destination unless it's absolutely necessary (maybe you're using a library that only outputs to stdout??? clearly not the case here).

I think as a good habit you should prepare your data ahead of time as a string, then open your file and write the whole thing at once. This is because input/output operations are the longer you have a file handle open, the more likely an error is to occur with this file (file lock error, i/o error, etc). Just doing it all in one operation leaves no question for when it might have gone wrong.

Here's an example:

```
out_lines = []
for bamfile in bamfiles:
    filename = bamfile.split('/')[-1]
    out_lines.append('Filename: %s' % filename)
    samtoolsin = subprocess.Popen(["/share/bin/samtools/samtools","view",bamfile],
                                  stdout=subprocess.PIPE,bufsize=1)
    linelist= samtoolsin.stdout.readlines()
    print 'Readlines finished!'
    out_lines.extend(linelist)
    out_lines.append('\n')
```

And then when you're all done collecting your "data lines" one line per list item, you can join them with some `'\n'` characters to make the whole thing outputtable; maybe even wrap your output statement in a `with` block, for additional safety (will automatically close your output handle even if something goes wrong):

```
out_string = '\n'.join(out_lines)
out_filename = 'myfile.txt'
with open(out_filename, 'w') as outf:
    outf.write(out_string)
print "YAY MY STDOUT IS UNTAINTED!!!"
```

However if you have lots of data to write, you **could** write it one piece at a time. I don't think it's relevant to your application but here's the alternative:

```
out_filename = 'myfile.txt'
outf = open(out_filename, 'w')
for bamfile in bamfiles:
    filename = bamfile.split('/')[-1]
    outf.write('Filename: %s' % filename)
    samtoolsin = subprocess.Popen(["/share/bin/samtools/samtools","view",bamfile],
                                  stdout=subprocess.PIPE,bufsize=1)
    mydata = samtoolsin.stdout.read()
    outf.write(mydata)
outf.close()
```

Comment: With disk caching performance of the original should be acceptable.  This solution however has the drawback of ballooning the memory requirements if there were a lot of output.  Though probably nothing to worry about here, it is generally a good idea to avoid this if possible.  Same idea as using xrange (py3 range) instead of range, etc.

Comment: @Gringo: He didn't specify this requirement. Rarely do I ever write enough data to a file that this would be relevant. This is not the same idea as xrange because xrange doesn't deal with file i/o. Disk caching might help but it's still a bad practice to keep a file handle open for a large body of code.

Comment: Your comment contradicts itself.  To be honest the performance aspect of both approaches is irrelevant for non-huge amounts of data. xrange certainly is similar, it works on one piece at a time instead of all at once in memory.  Perhaps a generator vs list is a better example though.

Comment: @Gringo: I fail to see how my comment contradicts itself. Maybe the performance aspect isn't relevant, keeping a file handle open for an extended period always increases the risk of error. In programming  file i/o is always inherently more risky than doing something within your own program, because it means you have to reach out through the OS and mess around with file locks. The shorter you have a file open for, the better, simply because you don't control the file system from your code. xrange is different because it has nothing to do with file i/o, and FYI I rarely use xrange either; cheers

Comment: @Gringo: Took out the bit about performance, made it all about error-carefulness. Happy? :)

Comment: @Gringo: That's not true at all. You can do a lot of computation, taking a long time in your code, without writing megabytes of data. I understand why you think xrange applies, but it has nothing to do with my reasoning. It's a better coding practice to not have a bunch of open file handles hanging around primarily due to file locks. Your comment about xrange is irrelevant because there was never any concern for memory efficiency, and there rarely is! In any case you don't need to touch sys.stdout at all here, should stick with regular output variables, so your answer IS wrong.

Comment: @GringoSuave let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2753/discussion-between-machine-yearning-and-gringo-suave)

Comment: @Gringo: I appreciate your criticism and enjoyed the heated debate. Even though we disagreed on some points I still respect your views as it's clear you have a good reason for taking your stance. Thanks for ending it reasonably and have a very good night. :P

Answer (score 4):

If redirecting `stdout` works for your problem, [Gringo Suave's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7152903/8117067) is a good demonstration for how to do it.

To make it *even easier*, I made a version utilizing [contextmanagers](https://docs.python.org/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager) for a succinct generalized calling syntax using the `with` statement:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
import sys

@contextmanager
def redirected_stdout(outstream):
    orig_stdout = sys.stdout
    try:
        sys.stdout = outstream
        yield
    finally:
        sys.stdout = orig_stdout
```

To use it, you just do the following (derived from Suave's example):

```
with open('out.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    with redirected_stdout(outfile):
        for i in range(2):
            print('i =', i)
```

It's useful for selectively redirecting `print` when a module uses it in a way you don't like. The only disadvantage (and this is the dealbreaker for many situations) is that it doesn't work if one wants multiple threads with different values of `stdout`, but that requires a better, more generalized method: indirect module access. You can see implementations of that in other answers to this question.

Comment: Good idea.  This context manager exists in the contextlib module however, docs say since Python 3.4.

Comment: @GringoSuave Yep, the `contextmanager` function should be imported to use as a decorator; hence why I put `from contextlib import contextmanager` at the top of the code block.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another method I've used for printing to a file/log... Modify the built-in print function so that it logs to a file in the temp directory with the current time stamp, as well as print to stdout. The only real advantage to doing this within a script is not having to go and modify existing print statements.

```py
print('test')
```

```
test
```

#### Copy original print function to new variable

```py
og_print = print
og_print('test2')
```

```
test2
```

#### Overwrite existing print function

```py
def print(*msg):
    '''print and log!'''
    # import datetime for timestamps
    import datetime as dt
    # convert input arguments to strings for concatenation
    message = []
    for m in msg:
        message.append(str(m))
    message = ' '.join(message)
    # append to the log file
    with open('/tmp/test.log','a') as log:
        log.write(f'{dt.datetime.now()} | {message}\n')
    # print the message using the copy of the original print function to stdout
    og_print(message)
```

```py
print('test3')
```

```
test3
```

#### display file

```sh
cat /tmp/test.log
```

```
2022-01-25 10:19:11.045062 | test3
```

#### remove file

```sh
rm /tmp/test.log
```

Answer (score 2):

I am able to crack this using the following method. It will use this print function instead of builtin print function and save the content to a file.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import builtins as __builtin__

log = open("log.txt", "a")

def print(*args):
    newLine = ""
    for item in args:
        newLine = newLine + str(item) + " "
    newLine = (
        newLine
        + """
"""
    )
    log.write(newLine)
    log.flush()
    __builtin__.print(*args)
    return
```

Comment: Haha this is a nice trick, do you use this kind of trick all the time? :)

Comment: Yeah, especially in winter season. lol. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Changing the value of sys.stdout does change the destination of all calls to print. If you use an alternative way to change the destination of print, you will get the same result.

Your bug is somewhere else:

- it could be in the code you removed for your question (where does filename come from for the call to open?)
- it could also be that you are not waiting for data to be flushed: if you print on a terminal, data is flushed after every new line, but if you print to a file, it's only flushed when the stdout buffer is full (4096 bytes on most systems).

Answer (score 0):

In python 3, you can reassign `print`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

def other_fn():
    #This will use the print function that's active when the function is called
    print("Printing from function")

file_name = "test.txt"
with open(file_name, "w+") as f_out:
    py_print = print #Need to use this to restore builtin print later, and to not induce recursion
   
    print = lambda out_str : py_print(out_str, file=f_out)
    
    #If you'd like, for completeness, you can include args+kwargs
    print = lambda *args, **kwargs : py_print(*args, file=f_out, **kwargs)
    
    print("Writing to %s" %(file_name))

    other_fn()  #Writes to file

    #Must restore builtin print, or you'll get 'I/O operation on closed file'
    #If you attempt to print after this block
    print = py_print

print("Printing to stdout")
other_fn() #Writes to console/stdout
```

Note that the *print* from `other_fn` only switches outputs because *print* is being reassigned in the global scope.  If we assign *print* within a function, the *print* in `other_fn` is normally not affected.  We can use the *global* keyword if we want to affect all *print* calls:

```
import builtins

def other_fn():
    #This will use the print function that's active when the function is called
    print("Printing from function")

def main():
    global print #Without this, other_fn will use builtins.print
    file_name = "test.txt"
    with open(file_name, "w+") as f_out:

        print = lambda *args, **kwargs : builtins.print(*args, file=f_out, **kwargs)

        print("Writing to %s" %(file_name))

        other_fn()  #Writes to file

        #Must restore builtin print, or you'll get 'I/O operation on closed file'
        #If you attempt to print after this block
        print = builtins.print

    print("Printing to stdout")
    other_fn() #Writes to console/stdout
```

Personally, I'd prefer sidestepping the requirement to use the `print` function by baking the output file descriptor into a new function:

```
file_name = "myoutput.txt"
with open(file_name, "w+") as outfile:
    fprint = lambda pstring : print(pstring, file=outfile)
    print("Writing to stdout")
    fprint("Writing to %s" % (file_name))
```

Answer (score 0):

Something that I have used in the past to output some dictionaries is the following:

```
# sample dictionary
the_dict = {'a': 'no', 'c': 'yes', 'b': 'try again'}

# path to output to
dict_path = "D:/path.txt"

# script to output file
with open(dict_path, "w") as f:
    for idx, data in the_dict.items():
        print(idx, data, file=f)
```

The outputted file will look something like below:

```
a no
c yes
b try again
```

Answer (score -2):

Something to extend print function for loops

```
x = 0
while x <=5:
    x = x + 1
    with open('outputEis.txt', 'a') as f:
        print(x, file=f)
    f.close()
```

Comment: no need to use `while` and no need to close the file when using `with`