# Redirect print output to file in Python

Tags: python, file, printing, output

I am trying to redirect print output to a file in Python 3.4 - right now as it stands my script prints to the shell. I don't really need it to do that. Here's my code:

```
with open('Input.txt') as namelist:
    for line in namelist:
        line_lower = line.lower()
        a = namelist.readline()
        if fuzz.ratio(a, line) >= 95:
            print(fuzz.ratio(a, line))
            print(a + ": " + line)
```

I'd really like for what prints out as a result of this:

```
            print(fuzz.ratio(a, line))
            print(a + ": " + line)
```

To output to a text file.

What I found so far doesn't look like it works with Python 3, since print statements are now functions that require parentheses instead of statements. Here's an example of what isn't working:

```
f = open('out.txt', 'w')
print >> f, 'Filename:', filename  # or f.write('...\n')
f.close()
```

From:
[How to redirect 'print' output to a file using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152762/how-to-redirect-print-output-to-a-file-using-python)

Comment: Try `help(print)` from an interactive prompt and it will tell you all about the `file` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Python 3.0 introduced the `print()` function that supports an optional argument, `file`. So you can do things like

```
with open("myfile.txt", "w") as f:
    print("Hello, world!", file=f)
```

More info [here](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function)