# Is contextlib.redirect_stdout always a good idea?

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, stdout

Since I've learned of the pattern, I've been using

```
with open('myfile.txt','w') as myfile:
    with contextlib.redirect_stdout(myfile):
        # stuff
        print(...) # gets redirected to file
```

This lets me use the print syntax (which I prefer) to write to files and I can easily comment it out to print to screen for debug. However, by doing this, I am removing my ability to both write to file and to the screen, and possibly writing less clear code. Are there any other disadvantages I should know about, and is this a pattern I should be using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> is this a pattern I should be using?

In this particular case, I do think your pattern is not idiomatic, and potentially confusing to the reader of your code. The builtin `print` (since this is a Python-3x question) already has a [`file` keyword argument](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) which will do exactly what `redirect_stdout` does in your example:

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'w') as myfile:
    print('foo', file=myfile)
```

and introducing `redirect_stdout` only makes your reader wonder why you don't use the builtin feature. (And personally, I find nested `with` ugly. `\`-separated `with` even more ugly.)

As for the ease of commenting out (and for printing to both `stdout` and a file), well you can have as many `print` calls as you like, and comment them out as you need

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'w') as myfile:
    print('foo')
    print('foo', file=myfile)
```

> Are there any other disadvantages I should know about

Nothing definite I can think of, except that it may not be the best solution (as in this case).

EDIT:

From the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html):

> Note that the global side effect on sys.stdout means that this context
>   manager is not suitable for use in library code and most threaded
>   applications. It also has no effect on the output of subprocesses.

Comment: I agree with your assessment here, but it does beg the question -- why have `contextlib.redirect_stdout` in the first place?  And I think that the answer is so that you can send output of functions that you don't control whereever you want (think about `dis.dis` for example)

Comment: @mgilson Maybe you need to teach me about the `dis.dis` example you had in mind. I'm not sure why we don't just use the `file` argument of that function. The reason I think `redirect_stdout` exists, though just my guess, is because not every API has a `file` option like `print` and `dis.dis`.

Comment: Well, it appears I choose a poor example.  [In python2.7, `dis.dis`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#dis.dis) doesn't have a `file` argument and I didn't realize they added it sometime in python3.x (probably the same time they added `redirect_stdout` to `contextlib` :-P)

Comment: @mgilson If the old `dis.dis` lacked the `file` argument (and my Python age isn't old enough to know that), then yeah, I agree that's a use case of `redirect_stdout`. There probably still exist APIs like that, and so `redirect_stdout` will be around for while.

Comment: Many good points. I didn't consider the threaded implications.

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152762/how-to-redirect-print-output-to-a-file-using-python), about how to do exactly what you've been doing has quite a few comments and answers about the drawbacks of redirecting `stdout`, especially this comment to one of the answers:

> With disk caching performance of the original should be acceptable. This solution however has the drawback of ballooning the memory requirements if there were a lot of output. Though probably nothing to worry about here, it is generally a good idea to avoid this if possible. Same idea as using xrange (py3 range) instead of range, etc. – Gringo Suave