# python redirect stdout with print function, is it possible to extend to multiple outputs, and what's the timing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, stdout

I have read several questions on how to use print function to write on file by redirecting standard output. I find it potentially useful for logging (where logging module is sometimes inconvenient), but I wonder if there is a way to send the output to multiple destinations. 
Basically suggested solutions are either:

1. Reassign stdout with `sys.stdout=f`  #f is something that looks like a file
2. Use `contextlib.redirect_stdout`

So every time there is a `print(something)` in code `something`
is redirected on `f`. I am looking for something like

```
redirect_stdout([sys.stdout,f])
```

that outputs every `something` to both file `f` and the usual output.

Also, what is the timing of the print output (meaning if there is a function with
multiple print statements, when is the content flushed on f and stdout, and what if there is an error?)?

I did some investigation, but couldn't find a solution, so I think this is above my knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

In Python-3 the built-in `print` function already has a `file` keyword argument that redirects the output to a specified file. So a simple way to send the output to multiple destinations would be to use two `print` statements.

```
print(something)
print(something, file=f)
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35370893/7406166) for a more in-depth discussion.