# How to save the output of the print statements to a CSV file?

Tags: python, csv

I have written the following to isolate a very specific part of a file:

```
for line in open('120301.KAP'):
    rec = line.strip()
    if rec.startswith('PLY'):
       print line
```

The output appears as such

```
PLY/1,48.107478621032,-69.733975000000

PLY/2,48.163516399836,-70.032838888053

PLY/3,48.270000002883,-70.032838888053

PLY/4,48.270000002883,-69.712824977522

PLY/5,48.192379262383,-69.711801581207

PLY/6,48.191666671083,-69.532840015422

PLY/7,48.033358898628,-69.532840015422

PLY/8,48.033359033880,-69.733975000000

PLY/9,48.107478621032,-69.733975000000
```

Ideally what I am hoping for is the output to create a CSV file with just the coordinates. The `PLY/1`, `PLY/2`, etc. does not need to stay.

Is this doable? If not, at least can the `print` statements result in a new text file with the same name as the KAP file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect 'print' output to a file using python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152762/how-to-redirect-print-output-to-a-file-using-python)

Comment: It's quite different, read my question in its entirety

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `csv` module:

```
import csv  

with open('120301.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    for line in open('120301.KAP'):
        rec = line.strip()
        if rec.startswith('PLY'):
            writer.writerow(rec.split(','))
```

In a similar way, the `csv.reader` can easily read records from your input file.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#module-contents

If you are using Python 2.x, you should open the file in binary mode:

```
import csv  

with open('120301.csv', 'wb') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    for line in open('120301.KAP'):
        rec = line.strip()
        if rec.startswith('PLY'):
            writer.writerow(rec.split(','))
```

Comment: TypeError: 'newline' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: It's the difference between python 2.x and 3.x, see edit #1

Answer (score 1):

This is totally doable!

Here are a couple of links to some docs for writing/reading CSV:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

You could also just make your own CSV with the regular file reading/writing functions.

```
file = open('data', rw)
output = open('output.csv', w)
file.write('your infos') #add a comma to each string you output?
```

Answer (score 1):

You could open the file at the beginning of your code and then just add a `write` statement after the `print` line.

Something like this:

```
target = open(filename, 'w')
for line in open('120301.KAP'):
    rec = line.strip()
    if rec.startswith('PLY'):
       print line
       target.write(line)
       target.write("\n") #writes a new line
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work? Not sure what filename is supposed to be defining?

Comment: filename here is a variable (string), you should just pass it the name of the file you want to open, such as "file.csv"

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to redirect stdout to a file:

```
for i in range(10):
   print str(i) + "," + str(i*2)
```

will output:

```
0,0
1,2
2,4
3,6
4,8
5,10
6,12
7,14
8,16
9,18
```

if you run it as `python myprog.py > myout.txt` the result go to myout.txt