# Save Print output in csv file

Tags: python, csv

I want to save this print output to CSV file but this code is not working, how can I save this output to CSV?

```
import csv

for x in range(2000, 3000):
    print('hi', x, sep='')

f = open('op2.csv', 'w')
writer = csv.writer(f)
writer.writerow(print())
f.close()
```

I want to save on CSV like this

```
hi2000
hi2001
hi2002
```

Comment: Please take a moment to read [ask] and edit your question to include more details, including what you want the contents of the CSV to be.

Comment: The big change that needs to be made here is moving your `writer.writerow` to be inside of your `for` loop. Just like `print` executes once for that `range(2000,3000)` you also need to `writerow` once per iteration in that range.

Comment: If you only want one column, why use a CSV file?

Comment: @TimPietzcker I want one column with hi2000 and I will create more than 5 columns like hi3000, hi4000, etc in different rows, that's why I'm using a CSV file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save the output of the print statements to a new file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38832545/how-to-save-the-output-of-the-print-statements-to-a-new-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To write a row to a CSV file, the *writerow()* function argument should be an iterable object (e.g. list).

The following code will create a CSV file with one column of numbers ranging from 2000 to 2999.

```python
import csv

with open('op2.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['a'])  # output header row as first line
    for x in range(2000, 3000):
        writer.writerow([f'hi{x}'])
```

If want to format variables using the print() function then you can use [str.format()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method or [formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings) (also called f-strings for short). Code above uses f-string `f'hi{x}'` to format each value of x to a string of the form: hi2000, hi2001, etc.

Comment: It works but I need to save it with 1 columns, sep='' can't add to writer.writerow(['hi',x])

Comment: @RasedulIslam - use `writer.writerow([f'hi{x}']) ` to output hi2000, etc.