# Does anyone know how to save the output of this code to a file?

Tags: python

```
sentence = input('Please enter your sentence: ')
words = sentence.split()

positions = {word:index for index, word in reversed(list(enumerate(words, 1)))}

print(' '.join(str(positions.get(word)) for word in words))
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is not general enough, I think it should be "How to write a file in python", also, you may want to read the docs before asking here.

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html

```
with open('filename', 'w') as the_file:
    the_file.write(whatever)
```

Comment: I'm looking for an answer to my question though, is there any chance you could help.

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open('out.txt', 'w')
f.write('...\n')
f.close()
```

this info came from [How to redirect 'print' output to a file using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152762/how-to-redirect-print-output-to-a-file-using-python)
 ;)

```
f.open=('PathToFile', 'w')
sentence = input('Please enter your sentence: ')
    words = sentence.split()
    positions = {word:index for index, word in reversed(list(enumerate(words, 1)))}
    f.write(' '.join(str(positions.get(word)) for word in words))
f.close
```

Comment: I have already tried this but I don't know how to word it in with my code.

Comment: maybe like 
sentence = input('Please enter your sentence: ')
words = sentence.split()

positions = {word:index for index, word in reversed(list(enumerate(words, 1)))}

f.write(' '.join(str(positions.get(word)) for word in words))

Comment: commenting failed i changed the code in my answer above

Comment: thank you for your help.