# Keras model.summary() object to string

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I want to write a *.txt file with the neural network hyperparameters and the model architecture. Is it possible to write the object model.summary() to my output file?

```
(...)
summary = str(model.summary())
(...)
out = open(filename + 'report.txt','w')
out.write(summary)
out.close
```

It happens that I'm getting "None" as you can see below.

```
Hyperparameters
=========================

learning_rate: 0.01
momentum: 0.8
decay: 0.0
batch size: 128
no. epochs: 3
dropout: 0.5
-------------------------

None
val_acc: 0.232323229313
val_loss: 3.88496732712
train_acc: 0.0965207634216
train_loss: 4.07161939425
train/val loss ratio: 1.04804469418
```

Any idea how to deal with that?

Comment: How to get the output in dict format: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68128858/10375049

Answer (score 79, accepted):

With my version of Keras (`2.0.6`) and Python (`3.5.0`), this works for me:

```
# Create an empty model
from keras.models import Sequential
model = Sequential()

# Open the file
with open(filename + 'report.txt','w') as fh:
    # Pass the file handle in as a lambda function to make it callable
    model.summary(print_fn=lambda x: fh.write(x + '\n'))
```

This outputs the following lines to the file:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
Total params: 0
Trainable params: 0
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: New in version 2.0.6

Comment: Just as an additional comment: you can also use `line_length` as an extra argument to tune how long the output line will be. This is useful because sometimes the layer name is too long and it is therefore cut: `model.summary(line_length=80, print_fn=lambda x: fh.write(x + '\n'))`

Answer (score 36):

For me, this worked to just get the model summary as a string:

```
stringlist = []
model.summary(print_fn=lambda x: stringlist.append(x))
short_model_summary = "\n".join(stringlist)
print(short_model_summary)
```

Answer (score 24):

And if you want to write to a log:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

model.summary(print_fn=logger.info)
```

Answer (score 12):

I understand the OP has already accepted winni2k's answer, but since the question title actually implies saving the outputs of `model.summary()` to a *string*, not a file, the following code might help others who come to this page looking for that (like I did).

The code below was run using TensorFlow `1.12.0`, which comes with Keras `2.1.6-tf` on Python `3.6.2`.

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation
import io

# Example model
model = Sequential([
    Dense(32, input_shape=(784,)),
    Activation('relu'),
    Dense(10),
    Activation('softmax'),
])

def get_model_summary(model):
    stream = io.StringIO()
    model.summary(print_fn=lambda x: stream.write(x + '\n'))
    summary_string = stream.getvalue()
    stream.close()
    return summary_string

model_summary_string = get_model_summary(model)

print(model_summary_string)
```

Which yields (as a string):

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense (Dense)                (None, 32)                25120     
_________________________________________________________________
activation (Activation)      (None, 32)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 10)                330       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)    (None, 10)                0         
=================================================================
Total params: 25,450
Trainable params: 25,450
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Answer (score 10):

I stumbled upon the same problem as well!
There are two possible workarounds:

Use [`to_json()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize#to_json_and_tfkerasmodelsmodel_from_json) method of the model

```
summary = str(model.to_json())
```

This is your case above.

Otherwise use the ascii method from keras_diagram

```
from keras_diagram import ascii
summary = ascii(model)
```

Answer (score 8):

It's not the best way to do it but one thing you can do is to redirect stdout:

```
orig_stdout = sys.stdout
f = open('out.txt', 'w')
sys.stdout = f
print(model.summary())
sys.stdout = orig_stdout
f.close()
```

see ["How to redirect 'print' output to a file using python?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7152903/2915983)

Answer (score 6):

One option, although not an exact replacement for model.summary, is to export a model's configuration using `model.get_config()`. From [the docs](https://keras.io/models/about-keras-models/):

> `model.get_config()`: returns a dictionary containing the configuration of the model. The model can be reinstantiated from its config via:
>
> ```
> config = model.get_config()
> model = Model.from_config(config)
> # or, for Sequential:
> model = Sequential.from_config(config)
> ```

Answer (score 2):

As I came here to find a way to **log the summary**, I wanted to share this little twist to @ajb answer to avoid the `INFO:` at every line in the log file by using @FAnders answer:

```
def get_model_summary(model: tf.keras.Model) -> str:
    string_list = []
    model.summary(line_length=80, print_fn=lambda x: string_list.append(x))
    return "\n".join(string_list)

# some code
logging.info(get_model_summary(model)
```

which produces a log file as:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem. @Pasa's answer was very useful but I thought I would post a more minimal example: it's a reasonable assumption that you already have a Keras model at this point.

```
import io

s = io.StringIO()
model.summary(print_fn=lambda x: s.write(x + '\n'))
model_summary = s.getvalue()
s.close()

print("The model summary is:\n\n{}".format(model_summary))
```

An example of when having this string is useful: if you have a *matplotlib* plot. You can then use:

```
plt.text(0, 0.25, model_summary)
```

To write the summary of your model to your performance chart, for quick reference:
[image]