# Saving large output data of one program to be used by another

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

Let's say in a file `A.py` and I am computing value of some variable `x` by some lengthy procedure, such that code takes around 15-30 seconds to execute.

I want to use value of `x` in another program `B.py`.

I have thought of importing `x` to another file `B.py` but when `B` executes, it executes `A` again in order to calculate `x`. `B` takes another 1-2 minutes to execute, so it's essential that I just use the output `x`. I tried to put it under `if __name__ == "main"`, but how will I compute `x` then?

Also, I have tried copying the value of `x` to a text file as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152762/how-to-redirect-print-output-to-a-file-using-python), but `x` is a very large list (around 10000 length), so output just shows "..." and omits printing most of it.

Comment: @meow I don't get it. Even when I run C, everytime it will compute x again when the function is called, even though it's in if name == condition.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to use [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/pickle.html).

```
import pickle

very_long_list = [1,2,3]
file_name = "/tmp/very_long_list.pickle"

pickle.dump(very_long_list, open(file_name, "wb"))

del very_long_list

very_long_list = pickle.load(open(file_name, "rb"))
print(very_long_list)  # prints [1,2,3], we did it!
```

Comment: It still prints "..." for me

Comment: This is for saving the variable. Use `for el in in list: print(el)` if you really want to print the whole list to the screen but I thought the problem was saving the result…

Comment: Sorry for a late reply but `pickle` also doesn't seem to work. I have tried printing the list row wise (it's a 2D array) but it still prints `[array([a b x ... c d y]), array([e f g ... h i j], and so on ... `

Comment: I think nobody really understood your problem then. Is it to save the result of a long computation or to display the content of a long list? You're mentioning an array. Are you using `numpy`? Are you looking for [numpy print options](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html)?

Comment: The problem is to save a long (in terms of memory) result, of a long (in terms of execution time) computation. The result is a list of lists. I want to save it to a file, so that it it doesn't need to be computed again, and it can be easily loaded from that file. I am using `numpy` in the code but the final result is not a `numpy.ndarray` its type is  `<class 'list'>`. At present, using `pickle` to save to a file and then loading and printing it like `for i in range(row): print(x[i])` prints the form I mentioned in previous comment

Comment: If printing the whole array is crucial to you, then follow the numpy docs links I provided before.

Answer (score 0):

When you *don't* need to run `A.py` for any other reason except to produce `x` (to be used i `B.py`), then you could simply have the code that returns `x` in a function called `compute_x()` and then in `B.py` write `from A import compute_x` and call the function in `B.py`.

Comment: But will compute_x not take some time to execute everytime I execute B?

Comment: Ah, yes it will. If x never needs to be recomputed then saving it to a file is the way to go. There's various ways for that, and pickle as described by nicoco is maybe the most straightforward.