# Python - Get output of all prints

Tags: python, csv, output, stdout

I wrote a python script that has a lot of data prints to the user.
I now need to save all of the print statements to a single txt/csv file.

I wonder what is the fastest and most efficient way to achieve this.
I could do this for each row at the time but prefer to this once for the entire script.

Comment: Redirect `sys.stdout` to a txt-file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect 'print' output to a file using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152762/how-to-redirect-print-output-to-a-file-using-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can redirect the output:

Python script.py > file.csv