# I have bunch of python print functions. I want to write the output to a file

Tags: python, file-io, printing

I am using python 2.7, and currently, I have a python code that prints to screen. I have been piping the output from the python code to a file by using >> command in linux until now. I would like to know if there is a simple method of printing out the output to a file without having to change every print function. Is this possible in python?

```
def print1():
  print "something1"

def print2():
  print "something2"

...

def printN():
   print "somethingN"


def main():
   print1()
   print2()
   ...
   printN()

   //I would like all the output to be in a file
```

Comment: Do you want to print the output in the shell and write it to a file too?

Comment: What's the problem with with using shell redirection?

Comment: @VigneshSP I no longer need to print the output in the shell. I now need to just write it in to a file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152762/how-to-redirect-print-output-to-a-file-using-python

Comment: @MoiraJones I used shell redirection for quicker testing purposes. For the users, the results need to be out putted to a specific file.

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python write to file", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.  Stack overflow is not a tutorial or coding resource.

Comment: Check out Python's [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) package, which may be a better long term solution for your project.

Comment: If you solved it, I would suggest adding your edit as an answer and accepting it. Just for completness sake... :)

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution on : [How to redirect 'print' output to a file using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152762/how-to-redirect-print-output-to-a-file-using-python)

Below works for my code:

```
import sys

orig_stdout = sys.stdout
f = open('out.txt', 'w')
sys.stdout = f

main()

sys.stdout = orig_stdout
f.close()
```