# I want to know how I can write 'result' in the file

Tags: python

[image]

I want to know how I can write **result** in the file. This is my homework. I hope someone help me.
Thank you.

Comment: Please have a look at [the documentation for the `print` function](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#print) and the `file` argument in particular.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Paste your code directly to your question and apply [code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code). [An image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to redirect 'print' output to a file using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152762/how-to-redirect-print-output-to-a-file-using-python)

Answer (score 1):

Do not use print, instead assign that to a variable

```
text = 'something {} here'.format(where)
print(text)  # if you still want to print
f.write(text)
```