# Convert output to a log-file-like output directly to a log-file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a Python file `test.py` and its output is 5 lines. I want to redirect the output (these 5 lines) into a log file.
Is there a way to run the `test.py` and redirect directly the output as a **log-file** (**test.log**) in Python?

So if I have:

```py
print(blabla)
print(blablo)
```

Then the `test.log` will look like:

```
09/03/20 15:23:56:019 blabla
09/03/20 15:23:56:067 blablo
```

Comment: If you mean without changing the file than it's really not a Python question. Using Linux you can do `python test.py > test.log`. Otherwise...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to redirect 'print' output to a file using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152762/how-to-redirect-print-output-to-a-file-using-python)

Comment: @Tomerikoo. I tried this `python test.py > test.log`, but `test.log` is missing the timestamp.

Comment: Then what's wrong with using `logging` as suggested by Kalyan? It does exactly what you want. If you don't want to change everywhere it says `print` you can just do at the top of your program `print = logger.info` or something similar

Comment: The code form Kaylan is  how to make a log file from a scratch. My problem is how to redirect the output of a `python-file` to be a `file.log`  with the logging format.

Comment: I don't see the difference... You can use `filemode='a'` instead of `filemode='w'`

Comment: under `logging.basicConfig(filename="test.log")`the  `test.log` will be a log-file, but for me I have as a start `test.py`

Comment: `test.py` is the Python file you are actually running. `test.log` is the log file you create. You got me really confused now. Can you explain in the question why `logging` doesn't solve your problem?

Comment: I need to use `test.py` to make the `test.log`. The `test.log` has to be as log-file format. The code from Kalyan create just `test.log` with a lines from `logger.debug, logger.info`..etc.

Comment: Ok, we're going in a loop. Use `logging` in your `test.py` to create `test.log`...

Comment: This my problem. How to put the output of my `test.py` to make `test.log`. Even with `logging` it is not obvious.

Comment: So please explain why Kalyan's answer doesn't do what you want because it certainly seems so

Comment: For example: where in `logging` to add `tets.py`? and how the output of `test.py` will be in `test.log`? I understand the timestamp using `logging`.

Comment: What do you mean? You need to `import logging` inside `test.py`. Is your question how to do that ***without modifying `test.py`***?

Comment: I tried your suggestion (I am not getting what I want). I want to log what the `print()` methods (inside of `test.py`) print out, like using `py test.py > test.log `.

Comment: Well look I'm going to go down from this Merry-Go-round ride. If you want, [edit] the question with a clear description of what's wrong with using `logging`, providing a [mre] of your code with its output and the output you're aiming for with any restrictions you have. Right now I really can't understand how come `logging` (with the proper customization) doesn't give you what you need. I will check up if you edit your question but will not participate in this loop-conversation

Comment: I find the solution, thanks to you (when you sad to use `logging` inside of `test.py`) and @Kalyan. I misunderstood how to use `logging`.

Comment: Ok I'm happy to hear and glad I could help in any way... Sorry for the confusion, happy you can ask your questions more clearly in the future ^_^ It would help if you had an actual [mre] in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Python logging module.

```
#importing module
import logging

#Create and configure logger
logging.basicConfig(filename="test.log",
                format='%(asctime)s %(message)s',
                filemode='w')

#Creating an object
logger=logging.getLogger()

#Setting the threshold of logger to DEBUG
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

#Test messages
logger.debug("Debug Message")
logger.info("Just an information")
logger.warning("Its a Warning")
logger.error("Error message")
logger.critical("Critical level message")
```

[image: test.log File output]

Ref: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/logging-in-python/

Comment: This code create a log file. I am looking for to redirect the ouput of a python-file as a log file. please read again my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `file` parameter for [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print).

For example:

```py
f=open('/tmp/example.txt','x')
print('sample_text',file=f)
```

You might want to use [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) instead.