# Printing multiple solved Sudoku arrays to a text file

Tags: python-3.x, list, formatting, sudoku, txt

Having some issues with a print to `.txt` function. There are a lot of options available, and I've tried several methods, but I'm running into errors.

I've created a Sudoku solver that reads an amount of 9×9 arrays from a text file and solves all of them. I have a working function that prints them into the terminal, but I need to output the results, formatted as they are in the terminal, into a text file.

Is there someway to amend the print function below to achieve that? I have a semi-working separate function that outputs to a `.txt`, but in an unformatted method and only one of the four puzzle arrays I've been using.

Thank you for your help.

```
def print_board(board):
  
  for x in range(len(board)):
    if x % 3 == 0 and x != 0:
        print("- - -   - - -   - - - ")
    for y in range(len(board[0])):
      if y % 3 == 0 and y != 0:
        print("| ", end="")
      if y == 8:
        print(board[x][y])
      else: 
        print(str(board[x][y]) + " ", end="")
  return
```

This is the export function that is only displaying one array.

```
def export_board(board):
  
  outputfile=open('solvedpuzzles.txt', 'w')
  print(output, file=outputfile)
  outputfile.close()
```

This is the format I need to achieve, that is currently working in the terminal from `print_board`

```
4 8 3 | 9 2 1 | 6 5 7
9 6 7 | 3 4 5 | 8 2 1
2 5 1 | 8 7 6 | 4 9 3
- - -   - - -   - - -
5 4 8 | 1 3 2 | 9 7 6
7 2 9 | 5 6 4 | 1 3 8
1 3 6 | 7 9 8 | 2 4 5
- - -   - - -   - - -
3 7 2 | 6 8 9 | 5 1 4
8 1 4 | 2 5 3 | 7 6 9
6 9 5 | 4 1 7 | 3 8 2
```

Edit:
I have made some adjustments, and have this:

```py
def print_board(boards):
  
  output = ''

  with open("puzzleoutput.txt", "a") as file:
    for x in range(len(board)):
        if x % 3 == 0 and x != 0:
            output += (str("\n - - -   - - -   - - - "))
        for y in range(len(board[0])):
          if y % 3 == 0 and y != 0:
            output += (str(" | "))
          if y == 8:
            output += (str(board[x][y]))
          else: 
            output += (str(f"{board[x][y]} "))

    file.write(str(output))
    return
```

Can someone please let me know how to add a new line for the individual rows of 9? It prints out the array as such, and I think I've nearly cracked it

```
4 8 3  | 9 2 1  | 6 5 79 6 7  | 3 4 5  | 8 2 12 5 1  | 8 7 6  | 4 9 3
 - - -   - - -   - - - 5 4 8  | 1 3 2  | 9 7 67 2 9  | 5 6 4  | 1 3 8
 - - -   - - -   - - - 3 7 2  | 6 8 9  | 5 1 48 1 4  | 2 5 3  | 7 6 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you not simply replace the `print()` statement with a `writelines([])` statement?

```
output = []

with open("demofile3.txt", "a") as file:
    for x in range(len(board)):
        if x % 3 == 0 and x != 0:
            output.append("- - -   - - -   - - - ")
        for y in range(len(board[0])):
          if y % 3 == 0 and y != 0:
            output.append("| ")
          if y == 8:
            output.append(board[x][y])
          else: 
            output.append(f"{board[x][y]} ")


    file.writelines(output)
```

Comment: Thanks Lawrence. I'm very, very new to Python. This is giving me an error however, of:line 91, in print_board
    output.append(str(board[x][y]) + " ", end="")
TypeError: list.append() takes no keyword arguments

Comment: Hi Ian, sorry I was a little lazy with my copy and pasting, I'd think you could just remove the 'end=""' statement. Let me modify my answer!

Comment: I also changed to using string interpolation; note 'f"{bard[x][y]} "' - its a neater way of including variables in a string if you are running Python3.

Comment: Thank you mate. That's now printing all four boards that have been processed - but unfortunately not in the desired format. It's just printing the arrays flat out, as such:
4 8 3 | 9 2 1 | 6 5 ['4 ', '8 ', '3 ', '| ', '9 ', '2 ', '1 ', '| ', '6 ', '5 ', 7, '9 ', '6 ', '7 ', '| ', '3 ', '4 ', '5 ', '| ', '8 ', '2 ', 1, '2 ', '5 ', '1 ', '| ', '8 ', '7 ', '6 ', '| ', '4 ', '9 ', 3, '- - -   - - -   - - - ', '5 ', '4

and so on :( I had to amend the file.writelines(output) to file.writelines(str(output)) as it was returning an error message. Any idea how to retain the format?

Comment: Hey mate. I've edited my post, because I made some changes to the code. I think all I need to do is place each row of the array in its own line, but I don't know where to add the code. Would you happen to know? Thank you

Comment: Hi mate - I wasn't able to edit my last comment. I used output += (str(' \n ')) to add line breaks where needed, and was able to achieve the formatting. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Awesome! Well done! Sorry I wasn’t as helpful! Feel free to create your own answer and mark it as solved or I can modify mine to include your new line break :)

Answer (score 0):

### Preface

When I searched the web for a *solved* Sudoku, which is much harder than searching for Sudokus to solve. Here I found what I was looking for, so thank you for posting one.

That's what I want to give back, be it to you, be it to others who stumble upon this question someday.

### Printing to files

The `print` function that's a Python 3 built in has an optional parameter `file`, which defaults to `sys.stdout` for the `print` calls you already know. The best way to solve your problem is to pass an (again optional) parameter through your `print_board` function to `print`. The following script contains a modified version of your function. It not also shows the usage of `print` function's the `file` parameter but also removes the flaw of mixing up `x` and `y` (if we take `x` as the horizontal and `y` as the vertical coordinate) because you are processing rows in the outer loop. This script also contains a function that turns what you define as output into a board (I was too lazy to type a nested python list):

```
# The optional `output` parameter specifies an 
# open file; leave out to print to the console
def print_board(board, output=None):
  for y in range(len(board)):
    if y % 3 == 0 and y != 0:
        print("- - -   - - -   - - - ", file=output)
    for x in range(len(board[0])):
      if x % 3 == 0 and x != 0:
        print("| ", end="", file=output)
      if x == 8:
        print(board[y][x], file=output)
      else: 
        print(str(board[y][x]) + " ", end="", file=output)

# Read a bord from a string that was formatted by
# the `print_board` function
def text_to_board(text):
    text = text.strip()
    board = list()
    for line in text.split('\n'):
        if '-' not in line:
            row = list()
            for letter in line.split():
                if letter != '|':
                    row.append(letter)
            board.append(row)
    return board

text = """
4 8 3 | 9 2 1 | 6 5 7
9 6 7 | 3 4 5 | 8 2 1
2 5 1 | 8 7 6 | 4 9 3
- - -   - - -   - - -
5 4 8 | 1 3 2 | 9 7 6
7 2 9 | 5 6 4 | 1 3 8
1 3 6 | 7 9 8 | 2 4 5
- - -   - - -   - - -
3 7 2 | 6 8 9 | 5 1 4
8 1 4 | 2 5 3 | 7 6 9
6 9 5 | 4 1 7 | 3 8 2
"""

board = text_to_board(text)
print_board(board)

with open('puzzleoutput.txt', 'w') as f: 
    print_board(board, f)
```

### Performance considerations

Normally it's efficient to directly writing to file, I experienced it to be fast enough. So I'd not suggest build a text buffer that's written at once: String concatenation, especially if done for character by character, involves a lot of allocating and freeing memory operations.

If performance *really* matters, I'd recommend a redesign not only the `print_board` function but also of the board storage itself. And of course, a solid knowledge about how to *measure* performance.

### Further reading

#### print to file

- [`print` in: Built-in Functions — Python 3.10.4 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print)
- [How to redirect 'print' output to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7152762/2932052) and its answers