# Print to mixed outputs in Python 3?

Tags: python, io

There are standard methods to print the putput of a program to an output file like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152762/how-to-redirect-print-output-to-a-file). Is there a way to use the `print` function for different outputs? I understand that the loop

```
with open('out.txt', 'w') as f:
    with redirect_stdout(f):
        print('data')
```

only prints to the out.txt file once we enter the `with`-"loop". How can I use the same snippet to do instead

```
for i in range(isteps):
    # Do something with the program 
    with open('out.txt', 'w') as f:
        with redirect_stdout(f):
            print('data') # Writes in out.txt
            print1('Status') # Writes on the screen
```

Note that the `for` loop outside the `with`'s is part of a bigger program that makes some computation. I would like to print the data in the file but at the same time monitor the status of the program (displayed on the screen).

Comment: don't redirect `stdout`, just use file methods like `write` to write to file and `print` to print to screen/stdout. Another option is to use `file` argument of `print` function to write to file.

Comment: Sounds like you want a logging framework, maybe? [Logging HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-howto)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in many ways. Warning though: it’s never a good idea to hijack stdout or any standard descriptors. As well as just in general your logging/printing should be explicit in where it’s writing to.

With that out the way, you could hijack stdout. Although again, this is not the best approach.

```
import sys

print('This message will be displayed on the screen.')

original_stdout = sys.stdout # Save a reference to the original standard output

with open('filename.txt', 'w') as f:
    sys.stdout = f # Change the standard output to the file we created.
    print('This message will be written to a file.')
    sys.stdout = original_stdout # Reset the standard output to its original value
```

A somewhat cleaner way would be to use the `file` parameter of print:

```
import sys

print('This message will be displayed on the screen.')

with open('filename.txt', 'w') as f:
    print('This message will be written to a file.', file=f)
```

For your code with the loop you can either shuffle the code around so you can keep a handle on the descriptor for longer or take full control of the descriptor and manage it yourself.

taking control of the file:

```
isteps = 4

f = open('out.txt', 'w')  # since we moved this out of a with we need to manage the discriptor
for i in range(isteps):
    # Do something with the program 
    print('data', file=f) # Writes in out.txt
    print('Status') # Writes on the screen
f.close()
```

shuffling the code around so you keep the descriptor:

```
with open('out.txt', 'w') as f:  # No need to manage since we have the with
    for i in range(isteps):
        # Do something with the program
        print('data', file=f) # Writes in out.txt
        print('Status') # Writes on the screen
```

Comment: Ah crap, I should have written that the `with` is inside a loop.

Comment: You can edit your question to make it more accurate. @user2820579