# Python: save the help result to a variable

Tags: python, nltk

Using python and NLTK I want to save the help result to a variable.

```
x = nltk.help.upenn_tagset('RB')
```

for example.

**x** variable is assigned with None. The console prints the result of the help function but it doesn't save that to var x.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796492/python-temporarily-redirect-stdout-stderr should help.  You can redirect it to a StringIO object and then read from that.

Comment: https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/205

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source file of [help.py](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/master/nltk/help.py), it uses the `print` statement and doesn't return anything. `upenn_tagset` calls `_format_tagset`, which passes everything to `_print_entries`, which uses `print`.

So, what we really want to do is to redirect the print statement.

Quick search, and we've got https://stackoverflow.com/a/4110906/1210278 - replace `sys.stdout`.

As pointed out in the question linked by @mgilson, this is a permanent solution to a temporary problem. So what do we do? That should be easy - just keep the original around somewhere.

```
import sys
print "Hello"
cons_out = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = (other writable handle you can get result of)

do_printing_function()

sys.stdout = cons_out
print "World!"
```

This is actually exactly what the accepted answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/6796752/1210278 does, except it uses a reusable class wrapper - this is a one-shot solution.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to get output of tag explanation is by loading whole tag-set and then extracting explanation of only required tags.

```
tags = nltk.data.load('help/tagsets/upenn_tagset.pickle')

tags['RB']
```