# Better method of writing stdout to file

Tags: python, python-2.7

Normally when I write `stdout` to a file, I do it like this.

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open(myfile, 'w')
print "This is in a file."
```

Now, this method looks ugly to me, and I've heard here and there that there is a better method. If so, what is this better method?

Comment: Glad to see you on StackOverflow, mr. President. See this relevant/duplicate thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4110891/python-how-to-simply-redirect-output-of-print-to-a-txt-file-with-a-new-line-crea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also make use of the fact that `print` can actually wrote to a file.

```
with open("file.txt", "w") as f:
    print("Hello World!", file=fd)
```

**NB:** This is Python 3.x Syntax only as `print` is a function in Python 3.x.

For Python 2.x you can however do:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Otherwise the same can be achieved with:

```
with open("file.txt", "w") as fd:
    print >> fd, "Hello World!"
```

See: [print()](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#print) from Python 3.x Docs.

Answer (score 3):

Print directly to the file, using either

```
with open(myfile, 'w') as fh:
    fh.write("This is in a file.\n")
```

or

```
with open(myfile, 'w') as fh:
    print >>fh, "This is in a file."
```

or

```
from __future__ import print_function
with open(myfile, 'w') as fh:
    print("This is in a file.", file=fh)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it as shown in the other answers, but it gets kind of old specifying the output file in every statement. So I understand the urge to just redirect `sys.stdout`. But yes, the way you propose doing it is not as elegant as it could be. Adding proper error handling will make it even uglier. Fortunately, you can create a handy context manager to address these issues:

```
import sys, contextlib

@contextlib.contextmanager
def writing(filename, mode="w"):
    with open(filename, mode) as outfile:
        prev_stdout, sys.stdout = sys.stdout, outfile
        yield prev_stdout
        sys.stdout = prev_stdout
```

Usage:

```
with writing("filename.txt"):
     print "This is going to the file"
     print "In fact everything inside the with block is going to the file"
print "This is going to the console."
```

Note that you can use the `as` keyword to get the previous `stdout`, so you can still print to the screen inside the `with` block:

```
with writing("filename.txt") as stdout:
     print "This is going to the file"
     print >> stdout, "This is going to the screen"
     print "This is going to the file again"
```