# How to display output of print() in GUI python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am new in creating GUI. I am doing it in Python with Tkinter. In my program I calculate following characteristics

```
def my_myfunction():
    my code ...
    print("Centroid:", centroid_x, centroid_y)
    print("Area:", area)
    print("Angle:", angle)
```

I would like to ask for any help/tips how to display those values in GUI window or how to save them in .txt file so that I can call them in my GUI
Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python How to simply redirect output of print to a TXT file with a new line created for each redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4110891/python-how-to-simply-redirect-output-of-print-to-a-txt-file-with-a-new-line-crea)

Comment: You want to display the ouput of `print` as tha title says or the values of `centroid_x`, `centroid_y`, etc. as the question suggests?

Comment: You question is simple enough to answer but you should always provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so people can better understand the context of your question/problem and help the specific issues.

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter is easy and an easy way to do a GUI, but sometimes it can be frustrating. But you should have read the docs before.
However, you can do in this way.

```
from tkinter import *

yourData = "My text here"

root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root, width=100, height=100)
frame.pack()

lab = Label(frame,text=yourData)
lab.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to display the results of any operation in tkiner.

You can use `Label`, `Entry`, `Text`, or even pop up messages boxes. There are some other options but these will probably be what you are looking for.

Take a look at the below example.

I have a simple adding program that will take 2 numbers and add them together. It will display the results in each kind of field you can use as an output in tkinter.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

class App(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master

        lbl1 = tk.Label(self.master, text = "Enter 2 numbers to be added \ntogether and click submit")
        lbl1.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 3)

        self.entry1 = tk.Entry(self.master, width = 5)
        self.entry1.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

        self.lbl2 = tk.Label(self.master, text = "+")
        self.lbl2.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

        self.entry2 = tk.Entry(self.master, width = 5)
        self.entry2.grid(row = 1, column = 2)

        btn1 = tk.Button(self.master, text = "Submit", command = self.add_numbers)
        btn1.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

        self.lbl3 = tk.Label(self.master, text = "Sum = ")
        self.lbl3.grid(row = 3, column = 1)

        self.entry3 = tk.Entry(self.master, width = 10)
        self.entry3.grid(row = 4, column = 1)

        self.text1 = tk.Text(self.master, height = 1, width = 10)
        self.text1.grid(row = 5, column = 1)

    def add_numbers(self):

        x = self.entry1.get()
        y = self.entry2.get()

        if x != "" and y != "":
            sumxy = int(x) + int(y)

            self.lbl3.config(text = "Sum = {}".format(sumxy))

            self.entry3.delete(0, "end")
            self.entry3.insert(0, sumxy)

            self.text1.delete(1.0, "end")
            self.text1.insert(1.0, sumxy)

            messagebox.showinfo("Sum of {} and {}".format(x,y), 
                                "Sum of {} and {} = {}".format(x, y, sumxy))


if __name__ == "__main__":

    root = tk.Tk()
    myapp = App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```