# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for >>: 'builtin_function_or_method' and '_io.TextIOWrapper'.

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code:

```
fout = open(path + "/log.txt", "w")
while (True):
    mini_batch = train_graph_data.sample(config.batch_size)
    loss = model.fit(mini_batch)
    batch_n += 1
    if train_graph_data.is_epoch_end:
        epochs += 1
        batch_n = 0
        loss = 0
        if epochs % config.display == 0:
            embedding = None
            while (True):
                mini_batch = train_graph_data.sample(config.batch_size, do_shuffle=False)
                loss += model.get_loss(mini_batch)
                if embedding is None:
                    embedding = model.get_embedding(mini_batch)
                else:
                    embedding = np.vstack((embedding, model.get_embedding(mini_batch)))
                if train_graph_data.is_epoch_end:
                    break
            if config.check_reconstruction:
                print >> fout, epochs, "reconstruction:", check_reconstruction(embedding, train_graph_data,
                                                                               config.check_reconstruction)
            if config.check_link_prediction:
                print >> fout, epochs, "link_prediction:", check_link_prediction(embedding, train_graph_data,
                                                                                 origin_graph_data,
                                                                                 config.check_link_prediction)
            if config.check_classification:
                data = train_graph_data.sample(train_graph_data.N, do_shuffle=False, with_label=True)
                print >> fout, epochs, "classification", check_multi_label_classification(embedding, data.label)
            fout.flush()
            model.save_model(path + '/epoch' + str(epochs) + ".model")
        if epochs == config.epochs_limit:
            print("exceed epochs limit terminating")
            break
```

and I have got this error:
unsupported operand type(s) for >>: 'builtin_function_or_method' and '_io.TextIOWrapper'. 
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the below code to fix it instead of `print >>fout,"text"` (this is supported only in python 2.x).

```
fileOb=open("myoutput.txt","w")
print("text you want to print",file=fileOb)
```

Refer [How to redirect the output of print to a TXT file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4110891/how-to-redirect-the-output-of-print-to-a-txt-file) for doubts

Comment: how can I change this code `print >> fout, epochs, "reconstruction:", check_reconstruction(embedding, train_graph_data,config.check_reconstruction)`

Comment: use `print( "reconstruction:", check_reconstruction(embedding, train_graph_data,config.check_reconstruction),file=fout)`

Comment: there are 4 parameter，where `epochs` I should fix in?

Comment: I forgot to add them. You can add any number of arguments as long as they are before `file = fileOb`(and any other keyword arguments). use use `print( epochs,"reconstruction:", check_reconstruction(embedding, train_graph_data,config.check_reconstruction),file=fout)`