# Python auto-flush stdout and stderr to local text file at runtime

Tags: python, stdout, stderr, file-writing

I have a Python script to continuously monitor various sensors.  Periodically, my Python script uses print() statements.

My goal is to have my Python script send `stdout` and `stderr` sent to a file, in real-time.

My current solution is based off of the following two answers:

- [How to redirect the output of print to a TXT file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4110891/how-to-redirect-the-output-of-print-to-a-txt-file/4111084#4111084)
- [Redirect stdout to a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675728/redirect-stdout-to-a-file-in-python/22434262#22434262)

Here is my current code:

```
from contextlib import redirect_stdout, redirect_stderr
from os.path import join
from some_other_package import get_base_logging_path  # returns filepath (str)

def main():
    stdout_log_path = join(get_base_logging_path(), "stdout.txt")
    stderr_log_path = join(get_base_logging_path(), "stderr.txt")
    with open(stdout_log_path, 'w') as f1, redirect_stdout(f1), \
        open(stderr_log_path, 'w') as f2, redirect_stderr(f2):
            do_stuff()
```

Here is where I come to Stack Overflow: the files `stdout.txt` and `stderr.txt` are only modified when the script either errors out or I safely close it with `control-C`.

I would like (particularly `stdout.txt`) to be updated every time a new `print()` statement is executed in my Python code.  How can I have my program auto-flush `stdout` and `stderr` to the text file?

Note: I tried `python -u` and it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the buffersize of the file to 1 worked for me

```
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
import time
import sys

with open("foo.txt", "w", buffering=1) as handle:
    with redirect_stdout(handle):
        print("foo")
        time.sleep(30)
        print("bar")
```

what also worked is using print with flush keyword

```
print("foobar", flush=True)
```

but the latter may not be used if you cannot modify the print-statements